# Changing the units of an axis on a seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, graphing

I'm plotting some functions of distance where the functions oscillate with a characteristic distance, and I'd like the units of the x-axis to be in terms of this characteristic distance. For example if the characteristic distance is 200m metres, I want x=50 on the x-axis to be 0.25, x=100 to be 0.5 and so on.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = 0.6
d_mass = 1
energy = 1

L_osc = (4*(np.pi)*energy)/d_mass

osc_constants = d_mass/(4*energy)

def P(x):
    return ((np.sin(2*theta))**2)*((np.sin(osc_constants*x))**2)

def S(x):
    return 1 - P(x)

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 1000)
y1 = P(x)
y2 = S(x)

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(x, y1, y2), columns=['x', 'Oscillation Probability', 'Survival      Probability']).set_index('x')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot sns.lineplot() to the ax
sns.set_palette('Set2')
sns.set_style('ticks')
sns.lineplot(df, ax=ax)
ax.set_title('Plotting Functions in Matplotlib', size=14)
ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.5)

# Despine the graph
#sns.despine()
plt.show()`
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking fot the `plt.xticks()` function (alternatively: `ax.set_xticks()`).

In your code you could add the following line:

```
ax.set_xticks(ticks=np.linspace(0,20,5), labels=np.linspace(0,1,5) )
```

Where `ticks` correspond to the values in your data, and `labels` correspond to the values you display on the axis.

Comment: Its generally a bad idea to decouple the ticks from the data, for example if you zoom on the figure things may look wrong. 

I better approach might be to modify the `x` data (for example, add a new column in the dataframe with the rescaled values), so that everything is self-consistent.

Comment: Why not `df = pd.DataFrame(zip(x/20, y1, y2), ...)`? That way matplotlib can automatically set the ticks, also when the plot changes. Having the tick labels different from their numeric value is very confusing, e.g. when you want to plot more elements onto the same plot.